# Prestashop upload image

Tags: php, image, image-uploading, prestashop

I have Prestashop 1.4.9.0 installed with my PHP project. When I add a new product, I upload an image in PNG format, but when it is shown on the client side, the image is in JPG format.

How can you keep the image extension?

Answer (score 1):

Back Office -> Preferences -> Images

[image: Images section]